estimating channel parameters in wireless communication
"I have a complex dataset consisting of two files: one for data points containing pilot data and another for label data. I'm trying to estimate the channel parameters using a DNN model(tensorflow,keras functional API with 4 layers) for regression.
i have run the DNN model with 4 layer and first i splited the complex number into real and imaginary and concatenated. Despite implementing regularization, dropout, kernel initialization, and cross-validation, I'm still unable to achieve my desired Mean Absolute Error (MAE) of 0.002525. Currently, the best MAE I've achieved is 0.28. Do you have any suggestions on how I can improve my model to reach the target MAE?"

maybe ask on similar portals DataScience and CrossValidated
